# How can I use conditionals in Pine Script strategies?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to learn Pine Script, and for my first project wanted to build a simple Fisher Indicator strategy based off the code below (as made publicly available on TradingView by user HPotter):

```
Length = input(10, minval=1)
xHL2 = hl2
xMaxH = highest(xHL2, Length)
xMinL = lowest(xHL2,Length)
nValue1 = 0.33 * 2 * ((xHL2 - xMinL) / (xMaxH - xMinL) - 0.5) + 0.67 * nz(nValue1[1])
nValue2 = iff(nValue1 > .99,  .999,
            iff(nValue1 < -.99, -.999, nValue1))
nFish = 0.5 * log((1 + nValue2) / (1 - nValue2)) + 0.5 * nz(nFish[1])
plot(nFish, color=green, title="Fisher")
plot(nz(nFish[1]), color=red, title="Trigger")
```

As I understand the transformation, you perform an operation on a value, plot that value (nFish), and you get your Fisher Line. Take the value from one bar back  nz(nFish[1]), plot that, and you get your trigger line. When you get a crossover between the Fisher Line and the Trigger Line, you have a position you might be interested in trading near. My thought then, in creating a strategy was to implement the following:

```
"If the Fisher Line is above the Trigger Line now AND IF the Fisher Line was below the Trigger Line on the last bar, enter a long position"
```

Which I attempted to implement by way of:

```
if (nFish > nz(nFish[1]))
    if (nz(nFish[1]) < nz(nFish[2]))
        strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
```

However, this code fails to ever generate any position entries and any modification of the values within the if statement also fails to produce any output. How can I fix my conditional to implement the idea I want to test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not recommend learning by using source code that old. You could start with any version, but I'd recommend not using anything unless you see `//@version=4` near the top of the source code. I made this mistake when I first started, adapting an old script and learning an outdated version in the process.

So here I've modified the script for V4, note changes. Some syntactical, and declaring variables with the var keyword to initialize certain variables. In V4 you can't declare a variable while using the variable in the declaration. Additionally I replaced the `iff` with a ternary, which you will see used more often.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Fisher Transform Indicator by Ehlers - modified for V4", shorttitle="Fisher Transform Indicator by Ehlers")
length = input(title='Length', type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)

MaxHL2 = highest(hl2, length)
MinHL2 = lowest(hl2,  length)
var float nValue1 = na
var float nValue2 = na
var float nFish = na
nValue1 := 0.33 * 2 * ((hl2 - MinHL2) / (MaxHL2 - MinHL2) - 0.5) + 0.67 * nz(nValue1[1])
nValue2 := nValue1 > 0.99 ? 0.999 : nValue1 < -0.99 ?  -0.999 : nValue1
nFish := 0.5 * log((1 + nValue2) / (1 - nValue2)) + 0.5 * nz(nFish[1])
plot(nFish, color=color.green, title="Fisher")
plot(nFish[1], color=color.red, title="Trigger")
```

Next, the logic you're describing is called a `crossover`. It means the first argument crosses above the second. Familiarize yourself with `cross` and `crossunder` as well. So adapting this to a strategy we can make a crossover variable for simplicity's sake:

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Fisher Transform Indicator by Ehlers - modified for V4", shorttitle="Fisher Transform Indicator by Ehlers")
length = input(title='Length', type=input.integer, defval=10, minval=1)

MaxHL2 = highest(hl2, length)
MinHL2 = lowest(hl2,  length)
var float nValue1 = na
var float nValue2 = na
var float nFish = na
nValue1 := 0.33 * 2 * ((hl2 - MinHL2) / (MaxHL2 - MinHL2) - 0.5) + 0.67 * nz(nValue1[1])
nValue2 := nValue1 > 0.99 ? 0.999 : nValue1 < -0.99 ?  -0.999 : nValue1
nFish := 0.5 * log((1 + nValue2) / (1 - nValue2)) + 0.5 * nz(nFish[1])

longCross = crossover(nFish,nFish[1])
shortCross = crossunder(nFish, nFish[1])
plotshapePosition = longCross ? nFish : na

strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, when=longCross)
strategy.close('long', when=shortCross)

plotshape(plotshapePosition, style=shape.circle, color=color.green, size=size.small, location=location.absolute)
plot(nFish, color=color.green, title="Fisher")
plot(nFish[1], color=color.red, title="Trigger")
```

Note I also made a `crossunder`, just to have an exit for the strategy.

Additionally I make a variable to plot a shape, which is necessary for positioning when not using `overlay=true`. Sp the plotshapePosition returns na or the nFish value when `crossover`s happen. The `location.absolute` parameter uses this level to position the shape, whereas if you were plotting on the main chart it wouldn't be strictly necessary. `plotshape` can be handy when testing to see if your conditions are working.

Additionally, if you do have a condition you need to build manually instead of using a function like `crossover`, you can use boolean logic to build it out.

```
longCondition = nFish > nFish[1] and nFish[1] < nFish[2]
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = longCondition)
```